# How to get data by new twitter api 1.1 url ( https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ ) in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, twitter

I'm using MSTwitterEngine in my app, with twitter api update to v1.1, i'm not able to get user information, list of followers and send direct message.

I tried to call new api url but getting bad authentication in response.

Please see below snippet :-

Ref:- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list

```
 NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=%@",strUserName];


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *mRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[mRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[mRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData1  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error!=nil) {


}
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *json=[SBJSON new];
NSDictionary *responseDic=[json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
```

Resposne:-  {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Answer (score 0):

New twitter API requires login to fetch data from twitter, as they have mentioned in their documentation that authentication is necessary to perform any twitter related functionality.

So now to do any functionality either you should login using OAuth or Twitter framework

Comment: I'm logged in with twitter account and getting auth token. I'm unable to send login authentication data, there i think i'm missing some. How are send auth code or something with request that twitter know this url comes from authenticated user ?

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is fine, but only the thing is to set the selected twitter account, so do like this,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json"];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setObject:your_user_id forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters setObject:@"-1" forKey:@"cursor"];

TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:parameters requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
[request setAccount:your_twitter_account];
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
 {
     if (responseData) {

         NSError *error = nil;

         NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
         if([dict objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
         {

         }
         else
         {

         }
     }
 }];
[parameters release];
[request release];
```

This is working for me..Hope it will helps you..

Comment: I dont have TWRequest class, do you have some link to get this class? 

and will it work with MGTwitterEngine ?

Comment: just add the `Twitter.framework`. Yes it will work with MGTwitterEngine.

Comment: My app has minimum version of ios 4.3, It was ready to upload on app store but due to twitter i stucked.